# Is there a product that offers hexagonal dungeon tiles?

Tags: product-identification, battle-map, tiles

I've searched a lot and found a lot of do-it-yourself hexagon dungeon tile printing.

**Does anyone know of a finished product that uses dungeon tiles with hexagons instead of squares?** I'm looking for something exactly like Wizard's Dungeon Tiles but that uses hexagons instead of squares.

Comment: Relevant: [Squares vs. hexes on battle maps](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/squares-vs-hexes-on-battle-mats)

Comment: There have been small press low budget versions in print over the years for various games, especially TFT. I don't know how many of them were simply drawn on TFT hexes and then mimeographed. The ones I saw where mimeo on yellowish-beige cardstock.

Comment: They're useful if your adventurers are in a dungeon built by giant bees.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe buy some used Heroscape maps?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroscape